# LibreOffice Write headless mail merge script

Tags: scripting, libreoffice, open-office

Libre Writer from LibreOffice has an excellent mail merge feature. And an API to access most of the internal functions including mail merge.

I am looking for a bash (Linux) script that

- takes a document (.odt) and some data (.csv)
- calls the Libre Writer API (headless mode)
- performs mail merge to produce the merged document .odt (or .pdf)
- returns this document and an success status

I have been searching all of the web for such an example but there are just partial solutions (e.g. [Project Gotenberg](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/gotenberg)) available, no complete mail merge example.

My goal is to build a stateless Docker container to do just this mail merge process.

OpenOffice examples are welcome, too.